# Make comparison between 3 numbers in array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, oop

I'm trying to make comprasion between 3 numbers in array.

I'm gonna give code so you understand me exactly what i mean:

```
$array = ["rank1"=>10,"rank2"=>20,"rank3"=>30];
$number = 3
```

So if `$number` is equal to or less than `10` to display `rank1`, and if `$number` is equal or greater than `20` but less than `30` to display `rank2`.

I hope you understand me. Thanks

Comment: SO how far have you got with writing the code for this?

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop to compare each value in the array to `$number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code which can be extended for any number of **sorted** ranks:

```
$array = ["rank1"=>10,"rank2"=>20,"rank3"=>30];
$number = 3;

$finalRank = false;
foreach ($array as $rank => $value) {
    if ($number <= $value) {
        $finalRank = $rank;
        break;
    }
}
if (false === $finalRank) {
    $finalRank = $rank;
}

echo $finalRank;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP if...else...elseif Statements. Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp).

```
$array = ["rank1"=>10,"rank2"=>20,"rank3"=>30];
$number = 3;

if($number <= 10){
    echo $array['rank1'];
}
elseif($number >= 10 AND $number < 30 ){
    echo $array['rank2'];
}
else{
    echo $array['rank3'];
}
```